# How can I use Regular Expression to format an ID?

Tags: php, regex

I have got a fairly challenging set of requirements.

I have an ID with various combinations of digits, spaces and characters and would like to match and replace certain characters using regular expressions.

Here are the requirements:

1. IF the ID contains all digits and no characters, then we need to insert a space after the 2nd digit. Example, assume the ID is 12384499003833. After inserting a space after the second digit, the new value should be 12 384499003833.
2. Taken the same ID value of 12384499003833, if the the 3rd character is a D or N, then there should be no space. The value should look similar to this: 12**N**84499003833.
3. Again, using same value as an example, if the 10th *and* 11th characters are GG, then insert 2 spaces before GG. When the 2 spaces are added, the new value should look similar to 123844990  **GG**833
4. and final requirement: If the 3rd character is D or N and the 10th and 11th characters are GG, there should be no space after 2nd digit but 2 spaces after GG.
   Example output should look similar to this: 12**D**844990  **GG**03833

I am truly sorry but I am really stumped.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Here is a table of input values and their formatted output values

```
Input            | Output
12384499003833   | 12 384499003833
12N84499003833   | 12N84499003833
12D84499003833   | 12D84499003833
123844990GG833   | 12 3844990  GG833
12N844990GG833   | 12N844990  GG833
12D844990GG833   | 12D844990  GG833

$tid = $_GET["tid"];

// Connect to SQL Server database
include("../connections/TDConnect.php");

$tsql = "SELECT * FROM TC(dtops.dbo.tSearch, Name, '\"$tid*\"')";
```

Comment: If you're not familiar with regex - just don't use them, use regular string functions instead

Comment: This doesn't seem like an appropriate use of regexp in the first place.

Comment: The SQL addon really belongs in its own question. Don't worry it will get answered (after at least 5 people tell you to use prepared statements) :)

Comment: Thanks @Jason.

That was the reason for the original question but I am truly grateful for your help and close this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Regex should match all of your IDs (here is a [demo](http://regexr.com?33f58))

```
/(\d{2})([ND]?)(\d*)(GG[\d]*)?/
```

Then you can compose your output by combining the groups like this:

```
$pattern = "/(\d{2})([ND]?)(\d*)(GG[\d]*)?/";

function format($matches) {
  return $matches[1][0].(strlen($matches[2][0])>0?$matches[2][0]:" ").$matches[3][0].(strlen($matches[4][0])>0?"  ".$matches[4][0]:"");
}

//To Test this
preg_match_all($pattern, "12384499003833", $matches);
echo(format($matches)."<br/>");

preg_match_all($pattern, "12N84499003833", $matches);
echo(format($matches)."<br/>");

preg_match_all($pattern, "12D84499003833", $matches);
echo(format($matches)."<br/>");

preg_match_all($pattern, "123844990GG833", $matches);
echo(format($matches)."<br/>");

preg_match_all($pattern, "12N844990GG833", $matches);
echo(format($matches)."<br/>");

preg_match_all($pattern, "12D844990GG833", $matches);
echo(format($matches)."<br/>");
```

This outputs:

```
12 384499003833
12N84499003833
12D84499003833
12 3844990 GG833
12N844990 GG833
12D844990 GG833
```

Or you can use this approach which requires a LTrim() of the output but uses entirely regex and replace ([demo](http://regexr.com?33f5b)) (note that this might be a little harder to follow)

```
$pattern = "/(\d{2})(\d+)(GG[\d]+)?|(\d{2})([ND])(\d+)(GG[\d]+)?/";
$replacement = "$1 $2$4$5$6  $7$3";

echo(ltrim(preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, "12384499003833"))."<br/>");
echo(ltrim(preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, "12N84499003833"))."<br/>");
echo(ltrim(preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, "12D84499003833"))."<br/>");
echo(ltrim(preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, "123844990GG833"))."<br/>");
echo(ltrim(preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, "12N844990GG833"))."<br/>");
echo(ltrim(preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, "12D844990GG833"))."<br/>");
```

This is the output:

```
12 384499003833
12N84499003833
12D84499003833
12 3844990 GG833
12N844990 GG833
12D844990 GG833
```

Comment: Oh, this is fantastic @Jason. Thank you very much for your kindness. Just one followup question. How do I use with following query: $tid = $_GET["tid"]; // Connect to SQL Server database include("../connections/TDConnect.php"); $tsql = "SELECT * FROM TC(dtops.dbo.tSearch, Name, '\"$tid*\"')"; I need to use it with $tid

I added the query at top so it makes sense. Please see at beginning

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d{3})(\d{11} if match then replace with  $1 $2
(\d{2})([ND])(\d{6})GG(\d{3}) if match then replace with  $1$2$3 GG$4
(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{6})GG(\d{3}) if match then replace with  $1 $3 GG$4
```

**Very ugly und unelegant solution buth I belive it works.**